# Como trazer o resultado descritivo de uma consulta SQL que só traz letra

Tags: sql, sql-server, query, select

Na minha consulta eu quero trazer o estado civil de um funcionário, já localizei qual tabela ele puxa essa informação, porém ele traz abreviado, exemplo "S", que seria Solteiro, e na consulta preciso que traga a descrição.

```
SELECT ESTADOCIVIL FROM PPESSOA

C - CASADO;
D - DESQUITADO;
E - UNIÃO ESTÁVEL;
I - DIVORCIADO;
O - OUTROS;
S - SEPARADO;
V - VIÚVO;
```

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz fazendo favor?!

Comment: se houver uma tabela com as descrições faça um `join`, senão use um `case` para mudar a descrição que retorna. Procure por case, há muitos exemplos aqui no site

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use o case para resolver isso: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ESTADOCIVIL = 'C' THEN 'CASADO'
            WHEN ESTADOCIVIL = 'D' THEN 'DESQUITADO'
            WHEN ESTADOCIVIL = 'E' THEN 'UNIÃO ESTÁVEL'
            WHEN ESTADOCIVIL = 'I' THEN 'DIVORCIADO'
            WHEN ESTADOCIVIL = 'O' THEN 'OUTROS'
            WHEN ESTADOCIVIL = 'S' THEN 'SEPARADO'
            WHEN ESTADOCIVIL = 'V' THEN 'VIÚVO'
       END AS ESTADO_CIVIL
  FROM PESSOA
```

Comment: Beleza... Muito obrigado!

Comment: opa, a ultima linha do comando está fora do bloco reservado para código...